# How to Ignore methodA1() using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

I am mocking methodA(), and want to ignore methodA1(). How to do it?

```
public void methodToTest() {
   methodA();
   methodB();
}

void methodA() {
   methodA1();
   methodA2();
   methodA3();
}
```

Comment: Please define 'ignore'.

Comment: I dont want to check methodA1() functionality.. Want to just skip it.

Comment: Why not extend the class, override the method so that it doesn't do anything, then test that subclass. Don't think mockito can help you here. You can't pick and choose which methods to mock. Either the whole class is a mock or it isn't.

Comment: Its just a triggering method.. Wont it be too much doing, in the suggested way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend doing these kind of things when you're testing, because in a real scenario if you call `methodA()`, `methodA1()` will do something.

What you need is to refactor the code in case you don't want to call `methodA1` inside `methodA`.

Anyway, you could do it using `Mockito`:

```
MyClass mockMyClass = Mockito.mock(Myclass.class);
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(mockMyClass).methodA();
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(mockMyClass).methodA2(); 
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(mockMyClass).methodA3();

mockClass.methodA();
```

Or:

```
MyClass mockMyClass = Mockito.mock(Myclass.class);
when(mockMyClass.methodA()).thenCallRealMethod();
when(mockMyClass.methodA2()).thenCallRealMethod();    
when(mockMyClass.methodA3()).thenCallRealMethod();

mockClass.methodA();
```

Comment: This won't work. If you've mocked `YourClass` then `methodA` won't do anything either. The whole class is mocked. You can't selectively mock some parts of a class.

Comment: I had used @Mock annotation, It was not working.. I tried in the suggested way, and now its working.

Comment: Anyway, Let me follow what Eduardo has suggested. Not to skip any method as it will create trouble if any edge case hits in production code ;)